# Username in urls - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo, permalinks

I am working on a project which includes signup, login and users can post articles. However I want to include username of the user in article url. So I did like this in **routes.rb**

```
scope '/:username' do
resources :articles, :path => '/status',  only: [:create, :destroy, :show]
end
```

Now when I open project index which shows all articles, I am getting this error.

`No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"} missing required keys: [:username]`

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**
Here is the output of `rake routes`

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
         users GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
          root GET    /                               static_pages#home
          help GET    /help(.:format)                 static_pages#help
        signup GET    /signup(.:format)               users#new
         login GET    /login(.:format)                sessions#new
               POST   /login(.:format)                sessions#create
        logout DELETE /logout(.:format)               sessions#destroy
               GET    /                               users#index
               POST   /                               users#create
               GET    /new(.:format)                  users#new
               GET    /:id/edit(.:format)             users#edit
               GET    /:id(.:format)                  users#show
               PATCH  /:id(.:format)                  users#update
               PUT    /:id(.:format)                  users#update
               DELETE /:id(.:format)                  users#destroy
      archings POST   /:username/status(.:format)     articles#create
       arching GET    /:username/status/:id(.:format) articles#show
               DELETE /:username/status/:id(.:format) articles#destroy
```

Here is the code of routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users, shallow: true do
    resources :articles
   end
end
```

Comment: as the error is saying, you need to pass the udername in the url, as per your current route defn, but you didn't.

Comment: username in the url ? can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, some value may be `foo` .. also will work, but it needs value. Because you defined it like that `scope '/:username' do` ... so your correct url is `http://localhost:3000/foo/status`

Comment: but when I visit the url I am getting the same error.

Comment: show the output of `rake routes`

Comment: please check the question again added the output

Answer (score 0):

Although having really short URLs may be attractive you should not use a wildcard at the "lowest level" of your url schema - unless your application only really deals with a single type of resource. Adding a wildcard at the bottom level in your urls causes huge headaches since it will swallow every other route unless great care is taken.

I would really recommend that you use `/users/:username/articles`.

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
  resources :articles
end
```

This is a better restful design and it means that you do not have to blacklist usernames against a list of the other urls (and future urls) needed in your application.

### Added:

The output of `$ rake routes`:

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
   user_articles GET    /users/:user_id/articles(.:format)     articles#index
                 POST   /users/:user_id/articles(.:format)     articles#create
new_user_article GET    /users/:user_id/articles/new(.:format) articles#new
    edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)           articles#edit
         article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                articles#show
                 PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                articles#update
                 PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                articles#update
                 DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                articles#destroy
           users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                 PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
```

Comment: this gives me url like `domain/articles/article_id`

Comment: `shallow: true` will give you `GET|POST users/:user_id/articles`, `GET users/:user_id/articles/new` and the individual routes `GET|PATCH|DELETE /articles/:id`.

Comment: You can use `status` instead of `article` by passing the `path` option.

Comment: this is still giving me same url `domain/articles/article_id`

Comment: Then you are doing something really wrong. I have added the output to the answer.

Comment: Most likely in your routes

Comment: added the code of routes.rb. Please check if something is wrong.

Comment: actually there is nothing wrong with my routes. I think you misunderstood my question. With you code, article url will be same domain/articles/15 like this. I want to change the url of show action.

Comment: Well, then you misunderstood my answer.  It does not even attempt to fix your original code but tells you why having a `/:username/status` url is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: thanks but this is bad idea to have `domain/username/status/post_id` ?. I am trying to achieve something like this but it is showing error.